# ¿Cómo obtener columnas específicas de una base de datos utilizando el método `findAll` en `sequelize`?

Tags: javascript, mysql, nodejs, express, sequelize.js

estoy enviando un objeto json con todos los usuarios que tengan active en true pero quisiera que al momento de recibir los objetos enviarlos en la respuesta solo algunos datos no todos los datos por ejemplo me gustaria que en el json cada objeto solo tuviera id name y age
post data: estoy usando sequelize  como orm es una api en nodejs con express

este es mi modelo :

```js
'use strict'
const { Model , DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../db');

class User extends Model {}

User.init({

  id:{
    allowNull: false,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true,
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER
  },
  name: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  age: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    // allowNull defaults to true
  },
  qrcode: {
    type: DataTypes.TEXT,
    // allowNull defaults to true
  },
  active: {
    type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
  },


}, { sequelize, modelName: 'User' });   

module.exports = User;
```

este es el codigo de mi controlador :

```js
findActiveUser: async function (req,res){
        var users = await User.findAll({
            where: {active: true},
            })
            .catch(err =>{
                return res.status(404).send({message:err});
            });
        if(users) res.status(200).send({users:users});
    },
```

esta es la respuesta que recibo :

```js
"users": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "maria",
      "age": 25,
      "qrcode": "asdasdasd",
      "active": true,
      "createdAt": "2021-10-07T18:51:21.000Z",
      "updatedAt": "2021-10-11T00:37:58.000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "luis",
      "age": 25,
      "qrcode": "asdasdasdas",
      "active": true,
      "createdAt": "2021-10-07T18:51:21.000Z",
      "updatedAt": "2021-10-11T00:37:58.000Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

y lo que quiero es que esa respuesta solo contenga los name el id  y la age de cada usuario sin lo demas campos  como podría hacer ?esto porque mas adelante metere contraseñas y no quiero que este de aquí para allá

Comment: Agrega después del `where` la propiedad `attributes` a tu controlador  `attributes: ['id', 'age']`. De esta manera solo te devolverá el `id` y el `age`. Puedes ver más [acá](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42003778/8838721)

Comment: mil gracias ya lo había intentado pero no me estaba fijando en que no le estaba poniendo  "" a los atributos y me daba error ajajja

Comment: Agregué respuesta para no dejar la pregunta vacía, y por si a alguien en el futuro le sirve.

Answer (score 0):

Si necesitas seleccionar columnas específicas de tu consulta a la base de datos con `sequelize`, agrega la propiedad `attributes` con el nombre de las columnas específicas que requieres en el método `findAll`. Quedaría así:

```
findActiveUser: async function (req,res){
  var users = await User.findAll({
      attributes: ['id', 'age'],
      where: {active: true}
      })
      .catch(err =>{
          return res.status(404).send({message:err});
      });
  if(users) res.status(200).send({users:users});
}
```